# "Unrecognized character \xE2" in a Hello World program

Tags: macos, perl, osx-yosemite

I am trying to write my first perl "hello world" program on Mac OS X Yosemite and it shows this error when I try to run this using terminal:

```
Unrecognized character \xE2; marked by <-- HERE after
print <-- HERE
near   column 7 at test.pl line 4.
```

I couldn't figure out what was wrong in this program. Please help me out here.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print “Hello world”;
```

Comment: Couldn't help, as this site wont allow me to upload the picture of what I see. I will do my best to take you through.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print “Hello world”;

Comment: Error its showing:Unrecognized character \xE2; marked by <-- HERE after print <-- HERE near column 7 at test.pl line 4.

Comment: I did edit my question including the code and the error now.

Comment: Make sure you use a plain text editor, or an IDE, to write your code. Text processing software tends to play tricks with punctuation.

Comment: Would try doing that. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Change  the

```
“”
```

character in the print statement to

```
"
```

Example

```
print "Hello world";
```

Comment: To elaborate: Perl (like most other programming languages) only accepts straight quotation marks, `"`.  Your code above is using comma quotation marks (`“`... `”`), probably because it was typed in something like Microsoft Word with "smart quotes" turned on.

Comment: Thank you, now it works but why wasn't it working before? and how do I type these non curly double quotes?

Comment: @nishanth chava, Normally, you just press the appropriate key on your keyboard. If you used an editor designed for word processing rather than software development, it might have automatically replaced `"` with fancier quotes. In MS Word, pressing undo (Ctrl-Z) immediately after typing `"` undos the "upgrade".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure syntax like this ' should be proper. Check your perl file for syntax errors

perl -c testfile.pl

Answer (score 0):

While it is not directly connected to this case, there's also a different situation when `\xE2` error can appear, which can seem not obvious. One can also have a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space#:%7E:text=The%20zero%2Dwidth%20space%20character,the%20groff%20representation%20is%20%5C%3A%20.) in their string, which can also raise this error.

I couldn't see this character in notepad or notepad++, but I could see it in vim as `<200b>`. This character can be placed next to `{` and `}` characters when copying stuff from for example Microsoft Teams.

This link appears as the first one when searching for this kind of problem, so I thought it might be a good idea to post the solution here.