# Red underline (error) in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm working on a project in Perl for Bioinformatics. We're supposed to create a file (in this case, chrom_seq.txt) and then get Perl to read it. However, I think Terminal doesn't recognize the file, because I get an error corresponding to the h in chrom_seq.txt, and the whole bit shows up underline in red. I've tried retyping the file name and making new copies of the file, with no luck. Suggestions?

```
# PatMatch.txt => takes DNA sequence from user
# and returns the reverse complement
open ($DNA_Chromosome, “chrom_seq.txt”);
# Remove non-ATGC characters from strings
$DNA_Query =~ s/[^ATGC]//g;
$DNA_Chromosome =~ s/[^ATGC]//g;
```

Comment: What error did you get? What got displayed in red? Did you really use `“` and `”` instead of double quotes? You should always check if open succeeded, if only by using `open(...) or die($!);`.

Comment: try to add input example and output expected

Comment: Hi, the error that I get is "Unrecognized character \xE2; marked by <-- HERE after romosome, <-- HERE near column 24 at PatMatch.txt line 3." chrom_seq.txt does open on its own from Terminal. I've tried manipulating the "s as ikegami suggested, with no new results.

Comment: change  “chrom_seq.txt” to "chrom_seq.txt" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881571/unrecognized-character-xe2-in-a-hello-world-program/29881805#29881805

Comment: You should probably be adding `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of the script.  You should check that you opened the file successfully.  You should probably not be trying to edit the file handle with a regex.  You read a line of data from the file handle into some other variable, and then fix the contents:  `while (my $line = <$DNA_Chromosome>) { $line =~ s/[^ATGC]//g; ... }` or thereabouts. (You could abbreviate that to: while (<$DNA_Chromosome>) { s/[^ATGC]//g; ... }` using the 'implicit' variable `$_`.

Answer (score 3):

Diagnosis - there is something fishy with the quotes - stolen from ikegami and keety.

General advice: For troubleshooting reduce complexity. Use

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#print “chrom_seq.txt”;  # error: Unrecognized character \x93 in column 7 at 30282450.pl line 4.
#print 'chrom_seq.txt'; # 'works'
print qw(chrom_seq.txt); # last resort
```

output:

```
perl 30282450.pl
chrom_seq.txt
```

to get confidence in the diagnosis.

Remedy: Use a decent editor (hex view, encoding) and don't copy/paste from sources in fancy formats (e.g. PDF).